# Android, reset a value everyday

Tags: java, android, reset

I am developing a timer app that works in block of times (pomodoros) and I'd like to have a variable that keeps track of the number of blocks passed everyday, so it keeps counting within the same day but goes back to zero the day after.

I was thinking of implementing this by saving the "last recorded day" when updating this value, and everytime the program starts, check it agaisnt the current date and act accordingly. So I have:

```
    public void saveDailyPomodoros() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    int currentDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    sharedPrefs.edit().putInt("dailyPomodoros", dailyPomodoros).commit();
    sharedPrefs.edit().putInt("lastRecordedDay", currentDay).commit();
    showDailyPomodoros.setText(String.valueOf(dailyPomodoros));
}
```

which saves the value (I call this function when I change it), and

```
    public void updateSettings() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    ...

    int currentDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    int lastRecordedDay = sharedPrefs.getInt("lastRecordedDay", 0);
    if (currentDay != lastRecordedDay) {
        dailyPomodoros = 0;
        saveDailyPomodoros();
    }
}
```

That is called at the start of the program and when the user exits the preference screen.

It works fine on this second case, however if I kill the app / reboot device it doesn't work, even if the other preferences are being saved (I have got shared preferences for custom ringtones that are not resetted).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It might be that your shared preference is getting saved with a `null` after force close/reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try creating private preferences for your app like so:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("SOME_NAME",0);
```